# Remove duplicate values from a column of json objects in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove the duplicates in the previous_location column of which is currently a json object. I'd like to leave the row as a json object.

#### initialize list of lists

```
data = [['tom', 20, [{"location":"USA", "State":"CA"}, {"location":"USA", "State":"CA"}, {"location":"USA", "State":"TX"}]], 
        ['nick', 35, [{"location":"USA", "State":"PA"}, {"location":"USA", "State":"PA"}, {"location":"USA", "State":"ME"}]], 
        ['julie', 29, [{"location":"USA", "State":"WA"}, {"location":"USA", "State":"WA"}, {"location":"USA", "State":"HI"}]]]
```

#### Create the pandas DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'age', 'previous_location'])
```

#### print dataframe.

```
print(df)
```

| name | age | previous_location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tom | 20 | [{"State": "CA", "location": "USA"}, {"State": "CA", "location": "USA"}, {"State": "TX", "location": "USA"}] |
| nick | 35 | [{"State": "PA", "location": "USA"}, {"State": "PA", "location": "USA"}, {"State": "ME", "location": "USA"}] |
| julie | 29 | [{"State": "WA", "location": "USA"}, {"State": "WA", "location": "USA"}, {"State": "HI", "location": "USA"}] |

#### expected output

| name | age | previous_location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tom | 20 | [{"State": "CA", "location": "USA"}, {"State": "TX", "location": "USA"}] |
| nick | 35 | [{"State": "PA", "location": "USA"}, {"State": "ME", "location": "USA"}] |
| julie | 29 | [{"State": "WA", "location": "USA"}, {"State": "HI", "location": "USA"}] |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["previous_location"] = df["previous_location"].apply(
    lambda x: [dict(d) for d in set(tuple(sorted(d.items())) for d in x)]
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    name  age                                                         previous_location
0    tom   20  [{'State': 'CA', 'location': 'USA'}, {'State': 'TX', 'location': 'USA'}]
1   nick   35  [{'State': 'ME', 'location': 'USA'}, {'State': 'PA', 'location': 'USA'}]
2  julie   29  [{'State': 'WA', 'location': 'USA'}, {'State': 'HI', 'location': 'USA'}]
```

---

EDIT:

```py
def fn(x):
    out, seen = [], set()
    for dct in x:
        t = tuple(sorted(dct.items()))
        if t not in seen:
            out.append(dct)
            seen.add(t)
    return out


df["previous_location"] = df["previous_location"].apply(fn)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    name  age                                                         previous_location
0    tom   20  [{'location': 'USA', 'State': 'CA'}, {'location': 'USA', 'State': 'TX'}]
1   nick   35  [{'location': 'USA', 'State': 'PA'}, {'location': 'USA', 'State': 'ME'}]
2  julie   29  [{'location': 'USA', 'State': 'WA'}, {'location': 'USA', 'State': 'HI'}]
```